# Getting list of the files in a particular Adb device folder

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am working with an application which browses into the Video gallery of a device which uses Android OS following code starts the browsing process. This is what my guess is because the code is folliwed by DPAD_left and DPAD_center commands.

```
"shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.music/.VideoBrowserActivity"
```

I did not find much help where I can understand what does this command exactly do but assuming that my previous assumptions is correct that it helps browse in the video gallery of the phone, is there any command which I can use to list all the files in the same directory?

I tried to look for the command on ADB web sire but did not find anything like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
$ adb shell ls /path/to/directory/with/videos
```